# How to Configure IdentityManager

Tags: identityserver3, thinktecture, identitymanager

I'm at the early days of looking into IdentityServer v3 and IdentityManager, as I'm certain those guys are more clued up than I, but I cannot see how to configure the IdentityManager.

If we're deploying IdentityManager to a client, all the client want to do is "standard admin type stuff", such as

- create users
- unlock accounts (e.g. after 3 failed login attempts)
- suspend accounts (not paid your bill, tut tut...)
- delete users

..rather than amend claims, roles and suchlike (presumably these would be hidden from the Administrators).

**What am I missing?**

Or, is the IdentityManager supposed to be used by the implementation team installing the thing, and then the business administrators who deal with the topics listed above actually don't use IdentityManager at all, but a separate admin site we have to write? As far as I can make out all the pages, htm letc is within the nuget package so cannot be amended by me.

If it makes any difference, we're trying to create a public facing website that can be logged into, but the users are only created by the company, whose admin site to create & administer the users is IP restricted / not public facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Manager is aimed at developers and internal administrators for testing and initial configuration purposes, as opposed to end users.

Check out https://vimeo.com/125426951 by the repo's author. I think it's explicitly stated at around the 1 minute mark. It's mentioned on the Github issue tracker quite frequently too.

Also, it's not that extensible yet, so you won't be able to brand it or remove sections (such as your requirement of no claims).

Comment: Thanks Scott. That mirrors my understanding of IM - in fact I'd watched that vid but the part about it being really for Devs had passed me by. I guess all the functionality or new users must be somewhere in IdentityServer its self or MembershipReboot... I'd best go hunting. Thanks